# df.value_counts() not working in jupyter notebook; pandas update needed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I would like to do a df.value_counts() in my jupyter notebook (to generate row counts by unique combination of columns in my dataframe).

The ability to do df.value_counts() is a recent functionality added to Python; specifically pandas 1.1.0 (see link [1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html)).  This works just fine when I run the command on my dataframe in a google colaboratory notebook.However, when I do the same on my Jupyter Notebook, it gives me an attribute error saying: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

I am using Python 3.6.4 and conda 4.10.01 and pandas 0.23.4. I want to upgrade to Pandas1.1.0 or higher. I tried to update Pandas from my notebook but it remains stuck with either of these options:
option1: !conda update pandas
option2: !conda install pandas = 1.1.0 (see picture below)

[image]

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue in my Jupyter notebook?

If unable to update Pandas, is there a way to replicate what I am trying to get (count unique combinations of values for columns 1:70 in a pandas dataframe)?

Comment: Have you tried updating `pandas` version?

Comment: The method DataFrame.value_counts() was added in pandas version 1.1.0. Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html

Comment: @Chris Not sure that's wise, if they're using Conda to manage their environment...

Comment: @NickODell Ah yes. That would be lot wiser. That was my quick and dirty solution ;)

Comment: That's right. Could you try running `! conda update pandas` ?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you add a space. The `!` signifies that it is a shell command and not a Python command. That's the only part that matters.

Comment: I tried !pip install pandas == 1.1.0 and it worked. It seems that conda is having problems for some reason in my environment?